# C++ memcpy code that I can't translate to C# with a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to write a c++ lib to c# and have a block of code I have no idea how to translate it to c#.  I first thought it had something to do with a char array but then a long got put into it and I got totally confused.

```
    unsigned long TileSize = fh.TileSize;
    char * pDiffBuf = (char*)malloc(TileSize * 4);
    long Diff = 10;
    memcpy((char*)pDiffBuf+zi*4, &Diff, 4);
```

In one of my previous questions I learned I can use a MemoryStream with a EndianBinaryWriter to do simple stuff like

```
Memcpy(ScaleBuf, &VertScale, 4);
```

I create ScaleBuf as a Writer on a MemoryStream and Write out VertScale.  But now they are doing some math on the actual buffer ?  My Ansi C knowledge is to basic for me to read this.  Can anyone explain to me what he is doing here ?

I'm guessing he is taking the array of chars (if it is one) that had some memory allocated to earlier.  and then putting the value of Diff in it.  But why the calculation ?  calculate an offset in the array ?  I simplified this example btw in the real code that memcpy is part of a for loop and each loop Diff has another value.  The example is just a bit to long to put on here to keep things readable and concise to the point.

Update: With the comments supplied and answers I managed to make a translation added below the C++ source here.  I'm not sure if I missed anything, and don't exactly know yet how to unit test in C# so I'll first need to read up on that to see how I can test all of this.  If anyone sees a mistake I made I'll be happy to hear of it and I hope this will help others out as well.

## Entire code for reference

```
long hfzWriteTile2(hfzFile* fs, hfzHeader& fh, unsigned long TileX, unsigned long TileY, float* pTileData) {

    if(!fs)
        return LIBHFZ_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;

    if(!pTileData)
        return LIBHFZ_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;

    unsigned long i, j;
    long TempInt;
    float f;
    float HFmin, HFmax;
    char c;
    short s;
    unsigned long i1, j1, i2, j2, bnx, bny, zi;
    long FirstVal;
    float VertScale;
    float VertOffset;

    unsigned long nx = fh.nx;
    unsigned long ny = fh.ny;
    unsigned long TileSize = fh.TileSize;
    float Precis = fh.Precis;


    i1 = TileX * TileSize;
    j1 = TileY * TileSize;
    i2 = i1 + TileSize;
    j2 = j1 + TileSize;

    if(i2>=nx)  i2 = nx;
    if(j2>=ny)  j2 = ny;

    bnx = i2 - i1;
    bny = j2 - j1;

    // prepare buffer for line
    char * pDiffBuf = (char*)hfzMalloc(TileSize * 4);
    if(!pDiffBuf) {
        return LIBHFZ_ERROR_ALLOC_FAILED;
    }
    char * pOutBuf = (char*)hfzMalloc(TileSize * 4);
    if(!pOutBuf) {
        return LIBHFZ_ERROR_ALLOC_FAILED;
    }

    // get min/max alt in block (used for vert scale)
    HFmin = 0;
    HFmax = 0;
    for(j=j1; j<j2; j++) {
    for(i=i1; i<i2; i++) {
        // find max diff in line

        f = pTileData[(i-i1) + (j-j1) * fh.TileSize];

        if(j==j1 && i==i1) {
            HFmin = HFmax = f;
        } else {
            if(f<HFmin) HFmin = f;
            if(f>HFmax) HFmax = f;
        }
    }
    }

    // number of int levels required for this block
    float BlockLevels = (HFmax - HFmin) / Precis + 1;

    // calc scale
    VertScale = (HFmax - HFmin)/(float)BlockLevels;
    VertOffset = HFmin;
    if(VertScale<=0)    VertScale = 1.0f; // this is for niceness

    // write the block scaling
    char ScaleBuf[8];
    hfzMemcpy(ScaleBuf, &VertScale, 4);
    hfzMemcpy(ScaleBuf+4, &VertOffset, 4);

    // swap byte order if required (files use little endian)
    if(LIBHFZ_BYTEORDER_BIGENDIAN==hfzByteOrder) {
        hfzByteSwap(ScaleBuf, 4);
        hfzByteSwap(ScaleBuf+4, 4);
    }

    if(8!=hfzWrite(fs, ScaleBuf, 8)) {
        return LIBHFZ_ERROR_WRITE_FAILED;
    }

    // save block line-by-line
    for(j=j1; j<j2; j++) {

        // get first val
        f = pTileData[(j-j1) * fh.TileSize];
        FirstVal = (long)((f-VertOffset)/VertScale);
        long LastVal = FirstVal;

        // find max diff in line
        long Diff;
        long MaxDev = 0;
        for(i=i1+1; i<i2; i++) {

            // find max diff in line
            f = pTileData[(i-i1) + (j-j1) * fh.TileSize];

            TempInt=(long)((f-VertOffset)/VertScale);
            Diff = TempInt - LastVal;

            zi = i-i1-1;
            hfzMemcpy((char*)pDiffBuf+zi*4, &Diff, 4);

            LastVal = TempInt;

            MaxDev = MaxDev>abs(Diff)?MaxDev:abs(Diff);
        }

        // should we use 8, 16 or 32 bit pixels?
        char LineDepth = 4;
        if(MaxDev<=127) {
            LineDepth = 1;
        } else
        if(MaxDev<=32767) {
            LineDepth = 2;
        }

        // write line header
        char BlockBuf[5];
        hfzMemcpy(BlockBuf, &LineDepth, 1); // store line depth
        hfzMemcpy(BlockBuf+1, &FirstVal, 4); // store first value (32bit precis)
        if(LIBHFZ_BYTEORDER_BIGENDIAN==hfzByteOrder) {
            hfzByteSwap(BlockBuf+1, 4);
        }
        if(5!=hfzWrite(fs, BlockBuf, 5)) {
            return LIBHFZ_ERROR_WRITE_FAILED;
        }

        // now write block
        char* pOutBuf2 = pOutBuf;
        for(i=i1+1; i<i2; i++) {

            zi = i-i1-1;
            hfzMemcpy(&Diff, (char*)pDiffBuf+zi*4, 4);
            switch(LineDepth) {
            case 1:
                c = (char)Diff;
                hfzMemcpy(pOutBuf2, &c, LineDepth);
                break;
            case 2:
                s = (short)Diff;
                hfzMemcpy(pOutBuf2, &s, LineDepth);
                break;
            case 4:
                hfzMemcpy(pOutBuf2, &Diff, LineDepth);
                break;
            }

            if(LIBHFZ_BYTEORDER_BIGENDIAN==hfzByteOrder) {
                hfzByteSwap(pOutBuf2, LineDepth);
            }

            pOutBuf2+=LineDepth;
        }

        long len = LineDepth * (i2-i1-1);
        if(len!=hfzWrite(fs, pOutBuf, len))
            return LIBHFZ_ERROR_WRITE_FAILED;
    }

    hfzFree(pDiffBuf);
    hfzFree(pOutBuf);

    return LIBHFZ_STATUS_OK;
}
```

## My C# Translation attempt

```
    public unsafe long hfzWriteTile(HfzFile fs, HfzHeader fh, UInt32 TileX, UInt32 TileY, float[] pMapData) 
    {

        MiscUtil.Conversion.EndianBitConverter endian = MiscUtil.Conversion.EndianBitConverter.Big;
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            endian = MiscUtil.Conversion.EndianBitConverter.Little;
        }

        if(fs != null)
        {
            return LIBHFZ_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;
        }

        if(pMapData.Length == 0)
        {
            return LIBHFZ_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;
        }

        UInt32 i, j;
        Int32 TempInt;
        float f;
        float HFmin, HFmax;
        char c;
        short s;
        UInt32 i1, j1, i2, j2, bnx, bny, zi;
        Int32 FirstVal;
        float VertScale;
        float VertOffset;

        UInt32 nx = fh.nx;
        UInt32 ny = fh.ny;
        UInt32 TileSize = fh.TileSize;
        float Precis = fh.Precis;

        i1 = TileX * TileSize;
        j1 = TileY * TileSize;
        i2 = i1 + TileSize;
        j2 = j1 + TileSize;

        if(i2>=nx)
        {
            i2 = nx;
        }

        if(j2>=ny)
        {
            j2 = ny;
        }

        bnx = i2 - i1;
        bny = j2 - j1;

        // prepare buffer for line        
        Int32[] pDiffBuf = new Int32[TileSize * 4];

        // get min/max alt in block (used for vert scale)
        HFmin = 0;
        HFmax = 0;
        for(j=j1; j<j2; j++) 
        {
            for(i=i1; i<i2; i++) 
            {
                // find max diff in line

                f = pMapData[i + j * nx];

                if(j==j1 && i==i1) 
                {
                    HFmin = HFmax = f;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if(f<HFmin) HFmin = f;
                    if(f>HFmax) HFmax = f;
                }
            }
        }

        // number of int levels required for this block
        float BlockLevels = (HFmax - HFmin) / Precis + 1;

        // calc scale
        VertScale = (HFmax - HFmin)/(float)BlockLevels;
        VertOffset = HFmin;
        if(VertScale<=0)    VertScale = 1.0f; // this is for niceness

        // write the block scaling
        MemoryStream ScaleBuf = new MemoryStream();
        EndianBinaryWriter ScaleBufWriter = new EndianBinaryWriter(endian, ScaleBuf);

        ScaleBufWriter.Write(VertScale);
        ScaleBufWriter.Write(VertOffset);
        Util.CopyStream(ScaleBuf, fs.pIoStream);
        ScaleBuf.Close();
        ScaleBufWriter.Close();

        // save block line-by-line
        for(j=j1; j<j2; j++) {

            // get first val
            f = pMapData[i1 + j * nx];
            FirstVal = (Int32)((f-VertOffset)/VertScale);
            Int32 LastVal = FirstVal;

            // find max diff in line
            Int32 Diff;
            Int32 MaxDev = 0;
            for(i=i1+1; i<i2; i++) {

                // find max diff in line
                f = pMapData[i + j * nx];

                TempInt=(Int32)((f-VertOffset)/VertScale);
                Diff = TempInt - LastVal;

                zi = i-i1-1;
                pDiffBuf[zi * 4] = Diff;

                LastVal = TempInt;

                MaxDev = MaxDev > Math.Abs(Diff) ? MaxDev : Math.Abs(Diff);
            }

            // should we use 8, 16 or 32 bit pixels?
            char LineDepth = '4';
            if(MaxDev<=127) {
                LineDepth = '1';
            } else
            if(MaxDev<=32767) {
                LineDepth = '2';
            }

            // write line header
            MemoryStream BlockBuf = new MemoryStream();
            EndianBinaryWriter BlockBufWriter = new EndianBinaryWriter(endian, BlockBuf);

            BlockBufWriter.Write(LineDepth);
            BlockBufWriter.Write(FirstVal);
            Util.CopyStream(BlockBuf, fs.pIoStream);
            BlockBuf.Close();
            BlockBufWriter.Close();

            // now write block
            MemoryStream pOutBuf = new MemoryStream();
            EndianBinaryWriter pOutBufWriter = new EndianBinaryWriter(endian, pOutBuf);

            for(i=i1+1; i<i2; i++) {

                zi = i-i1-1;
                Diff = pDiffBuf[zi*4];
                switch(LineDepth) 
                {
                    case '1':
                        c = (char)Diff;
                        pOutBufWriter.Write(c);
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        s = (short)Diff;
                        pOutBufWriter.Write(s);
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        pOutBufWriter.Write(Diff);
                        break;
                }
            }

            Util.CopyStream(pOutBuf, fs.pIoStream);
            pOutBuf.Close();
            pOutBufWriter.Close();
        }

        return LIBHFZ_STATUS_OK;
    }
```

Comment: What type is `zi`? I'd assume an integer, right?

Comment: I'll put the entire function here for reference, it seems with just part of code the context isn't clear.

If you see hfzMalloc in front of malloc thats just a wrapper methods that is being used but in the end it does a regular malloc

Comment: @kenny Is the intent of code is to build an array of `long`s?  If so, in .NET you shouldn't translate it verbatim.  Just simply declare variable `long[] diffBuff = new long[TileSize];` and stuff it with your longs by index.  C# is not C++ and translating verbatim one into another would not be right approach IMHO.

Comment: @LB2 the code serves to write the Tiles part of following file format

http://www.bundysoft.com/docs/doku.php?id=l3dt:formats:specs:hf2

Comment: @kenny Ok, taking a quick glance at the code, if I'm not mistaken, you indeed first stuff pDiffBuff as array of longs, and then take out longs late from the array.  The whole memory copying thing seems to be achieving just that.  So instead it seems you can just use regular C# array like I posted in comment above.

Comment: Thanks I'll write it like that at least, and see where it gets me.  I won't have results until I converted the entire source to C# though.  I'm actually a java developer and C# comes naturally to me but c++ is giving me headaches, I only have a one year basic Ansi C background, I know how to make a circular list and qsort in it ... thats it

Comment: @LB2 I'd point out one thing though - the original code does save longs, *but* it indexes by 4 byte segments, so it could possible mean that you might have to do some overlaps to emulate the functionality completely, so ints are probably a better choice anyway. 
@kenny I believe you shouldn't be indexing the integer array by `zi * 4`, just `zi` should produce the same behaviour as the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it creates a char array, and then copies the `10` value (the first four bytes of the long, whatever they are - that depends on endianness) to a given position in that char array.

Basically, think of the `pointer + zi * 4` as indexing in an array. If pDiffBuf was a byte array, this would be the same as saying `pDiffBuff[zi * 4]`.

I don't see how this could be useful. Could you show some more of the code?

Comment: I've added the full function as reference.  so pointer + is a shorthand for getting an index in an array , thanks that is actually allready quite enlightening

Comment: @kenny Interesting, it shouldn't be too hard to make this work completely. However, I would strongly recommend you to do a significant refactoring as soon as you have a working "port" - the code is absolutely horrible :D

Comment: completely agree, I got a fully compiled dll now and I'm testing with Nunit and debugging along the way.  Once I can at least read the file (not touching write yet) I'm refactoring a lot of it.  The errors will become checked Exceptions that I will throw instead of returning constants.  The original source didn't seem to be all to much object oriented while c++ is OO right ... maybe it's done for performance

Comment: @kenny It was probably written as pure C, which is still a part of C++. Also, many C++ programmers rely on C-style a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is unsafe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx

I don't mean don't do it. I mean it's `unsafe`. Start with something like this:

```
unsafe void hfzWriteTile2 (hfzFile* fs, hfzHeader* fh,
  UInt64 TileX, UInt64 TileY, float* pTileData)
{
}
```

The main thing that the `unsafe` keyword gives you is the ability to manipulate data directly through pointers. Here's a really basic introduction on how that works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

*sigh* I have to go do my job now. I'll come back to this later today and see how you're doing with it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I can use any bit of knowledge there is.  As I said in a previous comment, I'm actually a professional java developer, and well in java the VM will take care of most memory related stuff.

In my C# i turned hfzFile into a class HfzFile though do I still need a pointer then ?  or is it by default given as by reference then ?  In java everything is by value but is it in C#

Comment: @kenny Objects are passed by reference, so you don't need (explicit, unsafe) pointers. Even if you needed to pass the reference by reference (or a value type by reference), you can use the `ref` keyword. In non-interop code, usage of unsafe pointers is frowned upon - the only legitimate reason is native interop or performance critical code.

Comment: This code looks like it's trying to write to something like a video frame buffer, so it probably *is* performance-critical. That said, yes, OP should definitely avoid raw pointers--and especially writing through them--whenever possible.